# Swift: UIView not transitioning with NSTimer animation to correct CGPoints

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, nstimer

I am relatively new to swift and I'm working on a game in which a UIView moves when clicked to a random location on the screen. The problem is every time I try to add new code in the IBAction that executes all the animations for the UIView
it messes up the animation.
Here is the relevant code I have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var bottomConstraint: UIView!

@IBOutlet var topConstraint: UIView!

@IBOutlet var square: UIView!

@IBOutlet var SecondsScore: UILabel!

var timer: NSTimer!

var incrementA = 0.0

//====================FunctionA========================//


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        timer?.invalidate()
}

//======================Actions========================//

@IBAction func squareTapped(tapped: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    SecondsScore.text = "\(++incrementC)" //HERE IS THE CODE I ADD AND IT CHANGES THE ANIMATION OF THE UIVIEW
    animateSlide()
    timeIntervalForSquare()
}

@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
//=====================FunctionB=========================//

func rand() {
    var yaran = UInt32(bottomConstraint.center.y) - 40
    var xaran = UInt32(topConstraint.center.x) - 40
    square.center.y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(yaran)) + 30
    square.center.x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(xaran)) + 30
}

func timeUpSegue() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: nil)
    println("Segue: Game Over")
}

func timeIntervalForSquare() {
    timer =  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("timeUpSegue"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}


func animateSlide() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: {self.rand()}, completion: nil)
}


}
```

the UIView "Square" is the square that animates.
If anyone can plug this code into Xcode (with and without that line of code I have the comment next to) and see what's wrong I would be extremely grateful.

I apologize if the code is a little messy, I try my best to stay organized.

Thanks for anyone who can help me out at all!

Comment: I encourage you to look at the UIView's animations such as `UIView.animateWithDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, animations: () -> Void -> Void)` and the like. These are the proper way to animate views, and are quite powerful. In case you need even more animation options you could look inside CoreAnimation ... next step SpriteKit (I suppose your game is a 2D game)

Comment: "The problem is every time I try to add new code.... ",what kind of code do you add? animation code? "it messes up the animation", what the exact behaviour of the messed up?

Comment: You need to tell us what is wrong with your code. What do you expect to see, and what do you actually see.